# tortoise svn error show log for file - Path not found

Tags: tortoisesvn

I can right click any folder tied to SVN and say "Show log" it works. 
If I do the same thing for a file it says dir/subdir/subsubdir/default.aspx path not found error.. I couldn't figure out why..

Answer (score 56, accepted):

My Solution:
clear svn caches. (TortoiseSVN | Settings | Saved Data)
I used Win 7, TortoiseSVN 1.7.9

I had the same (as far as I understand) problem: 
Svn log (TortoiseSVN | Show log) returned a "path not found" error message for a specific file from my working copy.
The problem could be reproduced using the repo browser.
Svn update and even commit worked fine for that file from my working copy.
Svn log (update/commit) on other files in the same folder worked fine from my working copy.
My colleagues didnt have problems at all.

And yes: 
My Working copy was cleaned up, up to date and bound to a valid URL. The server was accessible via pasting URL to browser etc.

As I had the problem using the repo browser I never thought local (cached) data could cause the problem...

Comment: Thumbs up! Worked for me too :)

Comment: I had suffered this issue. But the solution worked for me, great!

Comment: ZOMG This answer is the beez kneez! Fixed my problem with "Path not found" during a merge > show log. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me. Only had to delete "Log messages (Show log dialog)" TortoiseSVN 1.8.8

Comment: This is the way to go ppl.

Comment: I had to clear everything under (TortoiseSVN | Settings | Saved Data) to make it work !!

Answer (score 2):

Try to do an "update" on that folder and see if the file wasn't actually deleted from Subversion.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows I've seen subversion get confused when the casing on the client and the server doesn't match - ensure you're casing is right.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be posted as comment. Besides, the question was asked almost 2 years ago.

Comment: @Heandel: Edited my answer - it should now provide valuable feedback. And; I don't think the age of a question really matters. The first source of information should always be previously asked questions.

Answer (score 1):

That was the same I Thought It would be, but, there are some other possibilities:
The path you are looking for may have suffered a change of type "rename" or "move"

Go through the repo-browse to get your file. 
Place the complete path (except the *filename.extension*) you need in the URL.
If the repo-browser doesn't get to the path specified, it'll get as far as it can recursively in the directory until it finds the problematic folder (a folder that for the youngest revision does not exist).

Do a Show log to the folder you get with the repo-browser to see if you find a Delete in that path

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, deleting cache did not solve it.

However, I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24629282/13624968

You have to make sure you commit the file! In my case, I only moved it to another folder via right click drag and drop, but did not commit.

As soon as I committed the file, the history showed up again.