# Show Log in svn doesn't show history after doing SVN Move versioned items here

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I try to do show log after moving folder with svn move versioned items here , it says path not  found . I have unchecked Stop on copy/rename. But i can do a diff with prev version of a file in moved folder.

What can i do to see the history in the show log ?

Or is it that that i have to commit the moved folder to see the history in show log? Right now I haven't committed the moved folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the log command, tortoise connects to the repository server to check the history of the files there. As they don't exist in the repository yet there's no history - so you're right in that you need to commit. Once you've done that they should show the full history including the move you've just done.

Hope that helps.